# Magento2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I am getting the below error in the console for the product details page.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How am I suppose to debug this error & solve it. Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I normally see this when the server returns an error (e.g. a 500 server error). The problem is that the server is returning plain text or sometimes even HTML and then the client app is trying to parse JSON from it thus throwing the error. I would recommend opening the chrome dev tools, navigating to the network tab, refreshing the page, and then look for the request in question and see what is actually getting returned from the server.